# Adapting img src change on mouseover to touch screen devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, mobile, touch

I'm using `mouseover`/`mouseout` and `data-src`/`data-hover` for graphic links that change an `<img>` `src` on hover.

How can I adapt the code to be touch friendly? Is there a cleaner/simpler way to implement the same functionality? I have already tried `vmouseover` with jQuery Mobile, and it didn't work.

I'm not using CSS `:hover`, because it's a specific graphic that must change color on rollover, and so I cannot use that as a starting point.

HTML setup for each link:

```
<a href="/books">
  <img id="book" class="image image-3" data-hover="/assets/graphics/ro-book@2x.png" data-src="/assets/graphics/book@2x.png">
</a>
```

Script:

```
$(".image-3").mouseover(function() {
  $(this).attr('src', $(this).data("hover"));
}).mouseout(function() {
  $(this).attr('src', $(this).data("src"));
});
```

Comment: did you look into mobile events? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events

Comment: Not sure how to start implementation of touch events, could you show me some example code?

Answer (score 3):

Don't forget you should be using touch events instead of mouse events for mobile devices.

I would suggest using the touchstart event.

```
$(".image-3").touchstart(function() {
  $(this).attr('src', $(this).data("hover"));
}).touchend(function() {
  $(this).attr('src', $(this).data("src"));
});
```

Comment: That didn't work but this did:

`$('.image-3').bind('touchstart touchend', function(e) {
        $(this).attr('src', $(this).data("hover"));
    });`

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

This worked finally, not sure what the syntax change did but I'm satisfied.

```
$('.image-3').bind('touchstart touchend', function(e) {
    $(this).attr('src', $(this).data("hover"));
});
```